# How do I display my API JSON data into a recycler view

Tags: java, android, database, api

I've just completed putting my API data into a JSONObject, now im trying to visualise the data in a recycler view. How would I go about by doing this, here is my code:

Where the comment saids pass to adapter, I presume that is where the recycler view would go. Sorry for the spaghetti code, I am very new to JAVA and object oriented. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCompanyInput = findViewById(R.id.companyInput);
        log = findViewById(R.id.log);
        mDescriptionText = findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
        mTitleText = findViewById(R.id.titleText);

        save = findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        save.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        //pull string from search query
        String companyInput = mCompanyInput.getText().toString();


        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        request = new Request.Builder().url(url + companyInput).header("Authorization", "k6DNRbTp-AnQWn51JBz5VuPiTl8jv4_etdzoMyhf").method("GET", null).build();
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick:" + url);

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                try {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject (response.body().string());

                    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("items");

//                    object.get("start_index");

                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse:"+ array.length());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject company = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                        Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: " + company);

                    }
//pass to adapter here than feed to recycler view





                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }





            }
        });

//        writeToDB(mCompanyInput.getText().toString().trim(), (mDescriptionText.getText().toString().trim()));
        showData();
    }

    public void showData() {
        RealmResults<Company> guests = realm.where(Company.class).findAll();

// Use an iterator to invite all guests
        String op = "";

        for (Company guest : guests) {
            op += guest.getName();
            op += guest.getAppointments();

        }

        log.setText(op);
    }

    public void writeToDB(final String mTitleText, final String mDescriptionText) {

        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm bgRealm) {
                Company user = new Company(mTitleText, mDescriptionText);
                bgRealm.insert(user);

            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

                // Transaction was a success.
                Log.v("Database", "Data Inserted");
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
                Log.e("Database", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
```

Here is what my API is spitting out in the log cat.
D/MainActivity: onClick:https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/search/officers?q=
I/MainActivity: onResponse:1
I/MainActivity: onResponse: {"links":{"self":"/officers/gPAqCDv52XAYJON4Z9SHCQOG-hU/appointments"},"description":"Total number of appointments 1","address_snippet":"27 Old Gloucester Street, London, United Kingdom, WC1N 3AX","description_identifiers":["appointment-count"],"appointment_count":1,"snippet":"","kind":"searchresults#officer","address":{"country":"WC1N 3AX","address_line_1":"Old Gloucester Street","premises":"27","locality":"London"},"matches":{"snippet":[],"title":[1,8]},"title":"FACEBOOK ADS S.R.L."}

Answer (score 0):

You may need, first of all, to create a POJO class to parse the response from the server. 
You have to implement a custom Adapter for your Recycler View.

Generally, you will initialize your adapter and recycler view in onCreate
and when the data arrives from the server you will just update the content of the adapter.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to get started with Recycler View, please check out [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview), [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) and [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/).